# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTToastAndroid.SHORT')

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, toast, short

[image]

Trying to use simple toast on iOs I get this error,
Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: u just need to link it using react-native link react-native-simple-toast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any React Native Component/API that ends in IOS or Android is only available for that specific platform. Since this is called ToastAndroid, it's only available on Android.

Comment: Yes, I just looked at the code and There was a call to ToastAndroid, replacing this with Toast fixed the problem, (Toast work for Android and iOs).